Terragrunt provider override
I’m trying to understand the structure and usage of Terragrunt. At the moment, I have created the following structure:
├── _common
│   └── instance_template.hcl
├── prod
│   ├── asia-south1
│   │   ├── applications
│   │   │   ├── ce-ping
│   │   │   │   ├── instance
│   │   │   │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   │   └── template
│   │   │   │       └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   └── lakehouse
│   │   │       ├── providers.hcl
│   │   │       └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   ├── infra
│   │   │   ├── vpc
│   │   │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   ├── vpc-firewall
│   │   │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   ├── vpc-subnet
│   │   │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   │   └── vpn
│   │   │       └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   └── region.hcl
│   ├── env.hcl
│   └── project.hcl
├── providers.hcl
└── terragrunt.hcl

The main issue is that I’m unable to override the provider configuration.
Here’s my base Terragrunt file:

locals {
  # Automatically load account-level variables
  project_local = abspath("${get_terragrunt_dir()}/project.hcl")
  project_parent = find_in_parent_folders("project.hcl", "/safe-placeholder")
  project_path = fileexists(local.project_local) ? local.project_local : local.project_parent
  project_vars = read_terragrunt_config(local.project_path)
  
  # Automatically load region-level variables
  region_local = abspath("${get_terragrunt_dir()}/region.hcl")
  region_parent = find_in_parent_folders("region.hcl", "/safe-placeholder")
  region_path = fileexists(local.region_local) ? local.region_local : local.region_parent
  region_vars = read_terragrunt_config(local.region_path)

  # Automatically load environment-level variables
  environment_local = abspath("${get_terragrunt_dir()}/env.hcl")
  environment_parent = find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl", "/safe-placeholder")
  environment_path = fileexists(local.environment_local) ? local.environment_local : local.environment_parent
  environment_vars = read_terragrunt_config(local.environment_path)
  
  
  # Extract the variables we need for easy access
  project_id  = local.project_vars.locals.project_id
  gcp_region  = local.region_vars.locals.gcp_region
  environment = local.environment_vars.locals.environment
}

# Generate a GCP provider block
generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<EOF
provider "google" {
  region = "${local.gcp_region}"
  project = "${local.project_id}"
}
EOF
}
# Configure Terragrunt to automatically store tfstate files in a GCS bucket

remote_state {
  backend = "gcs"
  generate = {
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }

  config = {
    project  = local.project_id 
    location = local.gcp_region 
    bucket   = "tg-state-${local.project_id}" 
    prefix   = "state/${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate" 
  }
}

# Configure root level variables that all resources can inherit. This is especially helpful with multi-account configs
# where terraform_remote_state data sources are placed directly into the modules.
inputs = merge(
  local.project_vars.locals,
  local.region_vars.locals,
  local.environment_vars.locals,
)


Within the structure there is a module lakehouse that requires an older version of the provider. I added providers.hcl file with new provider config, and modified terragrunt.hcl. Modified terragrunt
locals {
  # Automatically load environment-level variables
  environment_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))
  region_vars      = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("region.hcl"))
  project_vars     = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("project.hcl"))

  # Extract out common variables for reuse
  env        = local.environment_vars.locals.environment
  gcp_region = local.region_vars.locals.gcp_region
  project_id = local.project_vars.locals.project_id
}

# Terragrunt will copy the Terraform configurations specified by the source parameter, along with any files in the
# working directory, into a temporary folder, and execute your Terraform commands in that folder.
terraform {
  source = "tfr:///GoogleCloudPlatform/analytics-lakehouse/google?version=0.4.0"

  extra_arguments "provider_override" {
    commands = ["init", "apply", "plan"]
    arguments = [
      "-var-file=${get_terragrunt_dir()}/providers.hcl"
    ]
  }  
}

# Include all settings from the root terragrunt.hcl file
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

# These are the variables we have to pass in to use the module specified in the terragrunt configuration above
inputs = {
  enable_apis         = true
  project_id          = local.project_id
  region              = local.gcp_region
  deletion_protection = false
}


providers.hcl
terraform {
  required_version = "~>1.9.0"

  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = ">=5.9.0, , <6.0.0"
    }
  }
}


However, it didn’t work.
How should I correctly configure the provider override in this situation?

I think you want to override the https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-analytics-lakehouse/blob/main/versions.tf file. In that case you'll have to create one versions.tf in your parent module (that will override the one of the child module).

It was solved with generate block and override from terrafrom.
I created block called version_override, inside it I create file called version_override.tf. This file override main version.tf

The problem was solved by including the generation block with the required version. Within the block, the file was named version_override.tf, causing Terraform to override the main file version.tf.
